# confusion between finite difference methods and finite volume methods for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, finite-volume-method

I am new to numerical methods for PDEs, but I am seeing some confusing perspectives in two different common textbooks: Langtangen's book on Finite Differences and Leveque's book on Finite Volume Methods. I was hoping someone could help clarify.

I understand the difference between finite difference methods and finite volume methods. Finite difference use the value of the numerical derivatives at fixed points while finite volumn methods use the value of the control volumes between fixed interface points. The claim is generally that finite volume methods can preserve conservation laws better than finite differences.

The confusing thing is that I am seeing the same methods referenced in both books on finite differences and finite volume. In other words, I am seeing upwind scheme and Lax-Wendroff methods referenced in Langtangen's book for finite differences, and also in Leveque's book on finite volume methods. I am including snapshots of the relevant table of contexts sections for both books to show the overlap.

How can the same scheme belong to two different methods? Or am I misinterpreting something. Here are the excerpt from the tables of contents below.

**Langtangen:**

[image: Langtangen finite differences]

**Leveque:**

[image]

Comment: I think that you have stumbled upon one of the great misfortunes of numerical analysis: The taxonomy of methods is dated, unclear and seriously misguided. There are only two families of methods for any problem that you need to concern yourself with: Stuff That Works (STW) and Stuff That Doesn't Work (STDW). There are a million reasons why a given scheme may belong to STDW. On the other hand, all the schemes that belong to STW are there for the exact same reasons, and those reasons have nothing to do with either finite differences, volumes or elements.

Comment: @ekkilop haha, that is funny. Yeah, it is just a bit confusing because the textbooks setup different reasons for why one approach is better than another. When you look under the hood they use the same approaches. I will see if I can implement the finite difference version of upwinding versus the finite volume approach to upwinding, and see if I notice any differences.